# JQuery width animate doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to make div disappear and reappear by have the text disappear, the div collapsing, then the opposite with another div, using JQuery animate function but something's not working in the following code:

```
$(currentTab + " > p").animate({ opacity: 0},{
        duration: 500,
        complete: function(){

            $(currentTab).animate({width: "0", opacity: 0}, {
                duration: 500,
                complete: function(){

                    $(clickedTab).animate({width: "70%"}, {duration: 500, complete: function(){

                        $(clickedTab + " > p").animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 500);
                    }});

            }});

    }});
```

where currentTab and clickedTab are my div ids, like "#ct-1", and my html looks like that:

```
<div id="ct-1" class="content-div">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
<div id="ct-2" class="content-div">
    <p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
</div>
```

So the second animate doesn't run at all. I'm guessing this has somehting to do with the DOM, maybe I can't access a parent inside the animate ? maybe it's nothing to do with it...

Thanks in advance !

Robin

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle and we may be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `currentTab` is **ct-1** and `clickedTab` is **ct-2**, all of your animations are working in this fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/3k0x3c4L/**

You won't notice the width shrink unless `clickedTab` has a background, which I've added in the fiddle.